# Is it possible to execute query if where clause contains array and array does not contains any value?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT ticket_list.ticket_id, ticket_list.ticket_contact_name,ticket_list.ticket_account_name, ticket_list.ticket_email, ticket_list.ticket_phone, ticket_list.ticket_subject, ticket_list.ticket_description, ticket_list.ticket_status, ticket_list.ticket_due_date, ticket_list.ticket_language, ticket_list.ticket_priority, ticket_list.ticket_channel, ticket_list.ticket_classification, ticket_list.ticket_addedtime, assign_ticket.agent_id, customer_list.CU_Comp_Name 
from ticket_list 
INNER JOIN assign_ticket ON ticket_list.ticket_id=assign_ticket.ticket_id 
INNER JOIN customer_list ON ticket_list.ticket_account_name=customer_list.cu_user_email 
WHERE ticket_list.ticket_status IN('Open') 
  AND ticket_list.ticket_priority IN('Medium') 
  AND ticket_list.ticket_channel IN('Phone') 
  AND (customer_list.CU_Comp_Name IN('') OR customer_list.CU_Comp_Name IS NULL) 
  AND assign_ticket.agent_id IN('Ag_5') 
  AND ticket_list.deletion ='0' 
  AND assign_ticket.deletion ='0' 
  AND customer_list.Deletion='0'
```

This is my query. I am able to run it if i include some string in customer_list.CU_Comp_Name but not able to run it with blank.

How to execute query if there is no value in array..

Comment: Yuch https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: `IN('')`  looks for customer_list.CU_Comp_Name = '', so you have to remove this part if there is not data to lookup.

Comment: Not with you searching for an empty string or null in a column looks logically and syntactically valid to me..

Comment: but i am not sure if it is empty or not...If user select checkbox then it is not empty else it is empty.. In both case query must be execute that is my requirement..